# wordpress subdomain errors (2 wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

So I have an existing wordpress in Domain and installed a completely new wordpress inside a new folder (subdomain) inside the domain folder (domain/subdomain/). Now I want to access this new wordpress using subdomain.domain.com. Was able to do that but then having a problem with images. Was able to fix it but then Im having a problem now with files such as wp-blog-header.php. Here's more details hope anyone can tell me where I went wrong:

**.htaccess of Domain**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1
```

*.htacccess of subdomain is empty.*

**in wp-config I have these:**

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://subdomain.domain.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com/subdomain' );
```

**current error is**

```
Warning: require(/clientdata/apache-www/b/o/domain.com/www/subdomain/subdomain/wp-blog-header.php)
[function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
/clientdata/apache-www/b/o/domain.com/www/subdomain/index.php on line 17
```

as you can see, the subdomain in the path is doubled. what's causing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change both the config variables to use subdomains.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://subdomain.domain.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://subdomain.domain.com' );
```

This puts your .htaccess in full control and prevents wordpress from appending /subdomain anywhere.

Comment: thanks the error inside permalink page is now gone but still getting the error whenever i visit subdomain.domain.com or domain.com/learn

Comment: Reorder your main domain htaccess. Put the whole # wordpress block at the end.

Comment: Could you share your site's address so I can take a look?

Comment: @John I think you've modified your index.php. Change `require(./learn/wp-blog-header.php)` to `require(./wp-blog-header.php)`. Remove all instances of `/learn` in there or better just replace your `index.php` with one from a default wordpress installation.

Comment: Happy to help John. Glad to see your site's up and running :)

Comment: yeah. only problem now is the subdomain accessing the htaccess of the domain instead of it's own htaccess. but will create new thread for that. thanks again!